# My form in Microsoft Access doesn't access the tables' data when I reopen the file

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

When I fill out my form, the data registers perfectly in the respective tables. However, when I close Access and reopen it, the form becomes blank again. Here is my form:

[image]

As you can see at the bottom, it reads "1 of 1" which is wrong. The Microsoft's help page says that the form may have its field "Data Entry" set to Yes, but it's not the case. Previously, I was able to access the entries with my form, but it stopped. Perhaps, I screwed up something while writing some Visual Basic's functions... I would greatly appreciate the community's feedback. Thank you!

Comment: That empty `clinicalObservations` field is contained in a subform control on your main form (`inputForm`). We probably need to see that subform's Record Source and the Link Master/Child field properties of the subform control.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the main form (I think). There too, check the RecordSource. If it is a query, open that directly to see if it shows records. A screenshot of the form in design view, with the "Data" tab of the property sheet, might help.